# How to host react and node application on a shared hosting(Namecheap) without breaking on reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an app hosted on namecheap. When I reload any of the pages after logging in, the whole app breaks with a 404 error and when you visit the root URL again, everything comes back to normal. I had to buy a hosting account just to ask for this quiz in real-time.

Please note the app is just a demo so no big deal as much is not yet completed since we are just experimenting.

Log in and test for yourself what I mean maybe it might ring a bell.

Comment: I do not understand the question well but I suggest you use https://vercel.com because you can 1 use it for free 2 scale up when you need to 3 add as many apps as possible

Comment: Another alternative would be using nextjs.org because you can create APIs and React pages in the same app

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. so its not totally possible to achieve that only when i use nextjs?

Comment: This means I have to learn nextjs all again just to get this functionality?

Comment: no it is possible, you can write a custom server that do the things for your specific needs but that is overkill when NextJS can do that easily as it's what it's made for

Comment: Thanks...I am actually working my way around it. Thanks. I thought it would take me long to learn NextJs... 3 days with basics and am moving forward...

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Noted. Please just allow me to remove that part of the quiz since the link is no longer working